# Navigation bar doesn't show back button

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller with a table full of buttons that cause various settings pages to push in. I needed to add a new one, so I copied one of my existing ones, changed the VC, and off I go.

But there's no nav bar on the screen. I can see the navigation object in the storyboard and the editor simulates it's display. I compared it to the other pages that are displaying the bar, and they look the same.

I tried changing some settings, like "Hide Bottom Bar On Push" and that had an effect, but my attempts to get the bar to show up fail.

I looked at other questions that suggested it had something to do with naming, but I've tried various name fields - on the Navigation Item, the VC's Title, etc. - with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but the problem may be that in case the segue to the new View Controller Scene is set to modal, it would not have a Nav Bar, To be able to see one, you need to embed that in another Navigation Controller.